# Updating webpage from user input

Tags: php, html

I've made a very simple form which one user input field and a submit button. My question is how do I get what the user has entered into the field onto the actual web page? For example if the user enters their name into the text field and hits enter, how would I get that text to show up on the web page and stay there so when the next person visits the name will show up and the next person can do the same?

Comment: Save the name in the database.

Answer (score 1):

To store user input for use later, you should look in to implementing a database.  For some examples to get you started, check out the php documentation for mysql.  The doc page for `mysql_query` has some basic examples to get you started:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php